# Programatically adding [XmlIgnore] attribute in c# for serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Do anyone know how programatically add an `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to a class property in c#?

I'd like to do this to have just one class with one or two fields to be serialized as I'd need at run time.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just read it but, no, it's not my case. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to dynamically override XML serialization attributes by passing XmlAttributeOverrides object to XmlSerializer constructor.

```
XmlAttributes samplePropertyAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
samplePropertyAttributes.XmlIgnore = true;

XmlAttributeOverrides sampleClassAttributes = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
sampleClassAttributes.Add(typeof(SampleClass), "SampleProperty", samplePropertyAttributes);

var serializer = new XmlSerialized(typeof(SampleClass), sampleClassAttributes);
```

See [XmlAttributeOverrides Class in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Yeah! Implemented 'n' tested: it works!

Comment: Also note that the XmlSerializer(Type, XmlAttributeOverrides) constructor dynamically creates an assembly during runtime and doesn't cache it! So each call to this constructor will create another assembly which could lead to memory leaks. XmlSerializer is thread safe so if you are going to use this constructor, it's best to cache the XmlSerializer you created